# Value between two values of another df in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I Have two dataframes. One with a value and key and another dataframe with a range of the value and two keys. I'm trying to relate the value between the initial and final value and return the second key from the second dataframe to the first one(or a new one).

```
df1
Value Key1 
10    55
20    55 
30    35 
40    35 

df2 
Value Initial   Value Final  Key1  Key2 
     10              50        55    Y 
     10              50        35    Z
```

And I would like a result:

```
df3 
Value Key1 Key2
10    55    Y
20    55    Y
30    35    Z
40    35    Z
```

It's a calculation I ussualy make with CSE formula in excel, but it takes too long to process long datas.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with code, data, errors, current & expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your table isn't to big (this merge creates a cartesian product), you merge and then filter:

```
# Merge on Key1
dfm = df1.merge(df2, on='Key1')

# Filter on value in range of initial and final
df1['Key2'] = dfm.loc[(dfm['Value'] >= dfm['Value Initial']) & (dfm['Value'] <= dfm['Value Final']), 'Key2']

df1
```

Output:

```
   Value  Key1 Key2
0     10    55    Y
1     20    55    Y
2     30    35    Z
3     40    35    Z
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want `pandas.merge`:

```
>>> pd.merge(df1, df2)[["Value", "Key1", "Key2"]]
   Value  Key1 Key2
0     10    55    Y
1     20    55    Y
2     30    35    Z
3     40    35    Z
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> df1.join(df2[['Key1', 'Key2']].set_index('Key1'), on = 'Key1')

   Value  Key1 Key2
0     10    55    Y
1     20    55    Y
2     30    35    Z
3     40    35    Z
```